# Flask Socket IO Responding with Timeout error

Tags: javascript, python, flask, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to always have an updated table from my database in my webpage (real-time). For that I am using Flask and SocketIO. But I am getting the following error:

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NBIyASy&sid=bc2f86d8b04c4304aaf2a76211b3b6fa" host=pruebas-intranet.herokuapp.com request_id=2f725719-befa-4b1e-ba7b-5c025ad34a87 fwd="190.117.185.95" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Here you can see the code I am using in flask:

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, send

if(os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') is None):
    raise Exception("Esta Faltando la variable: DATABASE_URI")

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = “…”

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

socketio = SocketIO(app)

from models import User

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'login_post'
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_message = u"Por favor ingrese sus credenciales."

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

@socketio.on('solicitudes_id')
async def broad_consolidado():
    consolidado_data = Consolidado.query.all()
    await socketio.emit('consolidado', consolidado_data, namespace='/consolidado')

@app.route('/consolidado')
@login_required
def show_consolidado():
    return render_template("consolidado.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

And in my HTML side, I used as part of my code JS to show the table:

```
            <div style="overflow: auto">
 

                <table id="dtHorizontalExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>solicitudes_id</th>
                            <th>id_user</th>
                            <th>tipouso</th>
                            <th>tipoauto</th>
                            <th>credito</th>
                            <th>entidadcrediticia</th>
                            <th>id_auto</th>
                            <th>fecha</th>
                            <th>canalinput</th>
                            <th>ciudadcompra</th>
                            <th>hora</th>
                            <th>nombre</th>
                            <th>appellidos</th>
                            <th>numdocumento</th>
                            <th>numtelefono</th>
                            <th>correo</th>
                            <th>tipolicencia</th>
                            <th>tiempolicencia</th>
                            <th>trabajoaplicativo</th>
                            <th>tipodocumento</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>

                        <script type="text/javascript">
                              var socket = io.connect('https://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
                              socket.on( 'consolidado', function( consolidado ) {
                                  for (var i = 0; i < consolidado.length; i++) {
                                        console.log( consolidado[i].solicitudes_id );
                                        $( 'tbody' ).append('<tr> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].solicitudes_id+ '</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].id_user+'</td> <td>' +
                                            consolidado[i].tipouso+ '</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].tipoauto+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].credito+ '</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].entidadcrediticia+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].id_auto+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].fecha+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].canalinput+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].ciudadcompra+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].hora+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].nombre+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].appellidos+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].numdocumento+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].numtelefono+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].correo+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].tipolicencia+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].tiempolicencia+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].trabajoaplicativo+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].tipodocumento+'</td> </tr>')
                                }
                              })
                        </script>

                    </tbody>
 
 
                </table>
            </div>
```

Here are my console errors:

[image]

Thank you,

Jonathan Prieto

Comment: COuld you post the complete error traceback?

Comment: @ngShravil.py , I changed a bit my code and added the full error. In this change I am no longer using the jinja templating for the iteration, and instead I am using JS because in all the examples on internet, JS is necesary to connect the socket with the front END.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help answer your question but you can't change the `Request.sid` value, it is chosen by the server...

Comment: Thank you @Tom Smithson, but this error is probably due to another mistake I made progaming, because I never change this value.

Comment: @JonathanPrieto Okay, sorry I couldn't be much help! Good luck solving!

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP 503 error means that there was an error with the request resolution. I'm not sure if you've setup correctly `socketio`, but be sure to open and close the connection when needed.

Now looking at your snippet, you call the `socketio.emit` function and finish the execution. The problem is the this function needs to be async, so you should use the `async/await` keywords like this

```
@socketio.on('solicitudes_id')
async def broad_consolidado():
    consolidado_data = Consolidado.query.all()
    await socketio.emit('consolidado', consolidado_data, namespace='/consolidado')
```

This way you're ensuring the the `socketio.emit` finish executing before leaving the function.

Comment: Hi, I think I am getting the same error: ```at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NBKK4DZ&sid=0b6e588d605d482d9ece183697950812" host=pruebas-intranet.herokuapp.com request_id=488455f2-a301-4d3d-ade4-e38f08aa3116 fwd="190.117.185.95" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https```

Comment: Do you open the connection on the server? Can we have the full code.

Comment: Ok @Unicone , I updated the python code in my post.

Comment: Did you try to log `consolidado_data` value after the query to see if they're correctly getting queried? I'm not sure id you already handle it, but if `Consolidado.query.all()` is async, you should use the await keyword to wait until the data are parsed, and then emit them. `consolidado_data = await Consolidado.query.all()`

Comment: consolidado.query.all() works fine, I am not sure if it is posible but I am running my code in Heroku and for that I generated a Procfile, I don´t know if I should change it maybe. Nowadays it is like that: ```web: gunicorn app:app
```  I added await before consolidado.query.all() as you sugested and I have the same error.